# Like post button django

Tags: django, django-views

I found a ready-made solution that was not written by me. It worked, but I don't understand why. Can someone explain to me how this works?
Especially not clear what is the role of "value" and  "name" in form ?

html

```
 <form
          action="{% url 'likes_post'  post.pk %}"
          method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
      <button
            class="btn btn-success"
            type="submit"
            value="{{post.id}}"
            name="post_id"
    >likes: {{post.total_likes}}
    </button>

    </p>
  </form>
```

views

```
def likes_post(request, pk):
    post_for_like = get_object_or_404(Article, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post_for_like.likes.add(request.user.profile)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('artical_page', args=[str(pk)]))
```

urls

```
 path('like/<int:pk>/', views.likes_post, name='likes_post'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Dictionary {}
You have the key whick is "post_id" that you can call it in your Html as (name)
And you have the value in Dictionary which is "post.id"
So the dictionary will be
{"post_id" :"post.id"}
By the way
You can change (post_id) to any name LIKE (a_b_c)
But the value will be the same which is (post.id)
So that's the difference

Comment: Assalamu aleykum, in button value and name it is one dict? Thanks bro

Comment: Peace pe upon you - yeah bro they are in the same dict

Answer (score 1):

The combination of the `name` and `value` attributes forms a parameter that is sent to the server when the form is submitted. It will be sent as a name/value pair in the body of the POST request. Here is an example of what is posted to the server for `post.id` 12345:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 22
Origin: null
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

post_id=12345
```

In the view code, the server gets the `post_id` parameter from the request and uses this to identify which post the user has liked so that a like can be added for that post.

Comment: Thanks, but why one with a dot and the other with an underline, if they convey the same ID?

Comment: `post_id` is the name of the field/parameter from the HTML form. It could be called anything legal. It is extracted from the request in `id=request.POST.get('post_id')`. On the other hand, `post.id` refers to the `id` attribute of the `post` Python object within Django. This `post` object is passed to the template where it is accessed in your HTML form as the template variable `{{post.id}}`. You did not show the view code that renders the template, but it will be passing a `post` object to it.